# I am totally confused, any user can delete my solution? can we prevent this?

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, power-platform

I created a solution which contain 2 power apps + 2 workflows. and just for fun/testing >> i created a test office 365 user with no license on Power Platform >> this trail user was able to start a trial on the Power Platform (which is understandable)>> and what the surprise was; that this user was able to delete the solution i created !! so is this true? or i am dreaming? so i can assume that anyone can delete any solution he did not create/own? can we handle this please?

Comment: Is this solution created in default environment? What roles are assigned to user in this environment? Just want to confirm, did you share any app/flow within solution or whole solution with this user?

Comment: @GaneshSanap thanks for the reply . i am still inside the default environment, and i did not share the app nor the solution with this trial user